# Erro SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Estou fazendo o `select` abaixo e não consigo executar:

```
SELECT DISTINCT U2.NM_ORG AS [Orgão Subordinado], 
    U1.NM_ORG AS [Unidade Gestora],
       E.NM_EPG  AS [Nome Funcionário(a)],
       C.NM_CG   AS [Cargo Funcionário(a)],
       D.CD_DOC_VIA,  
       R.SQ_ROT_VIA,         
       min(M1.NM_CID) AS [Cidade Partida],
       min(M2.NM_CID) AS [Cidade Chegada], 
       CONVERT(CHAR(10), MIN(D.DT_INI_VIA), 103) + ' A ' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), MIN(D.DT_FIM_VIA), 103) AS [Período Viagem],
       UPPER(T.NM_TP_VIA) AS [Motivo Viagem],
       CASE
          WHEN O.CD_ORI_CST = 3 THEN 'VEÍCULO PRÓPRIO'
          WHEN O.CD_ORI_CST = 4 THEN 'AVIÃO'         
          WHEN O.CD_ORI_CST = 7 THEN 'CARRO ALUGADO'
          WHEN O.CD_ORI_CST = 8 THEN 'ÔNIBUS'
          WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T056TAER T WHERE T.CD_DOC_VIA = D.CD_DOC_VIA)  THEN 'AVIÃO'
          ELSE 'NÃO IDENTIFICADO'          
       END AS [Meio Transporte],

        RTRIM(B.CD_TAR_AER) AS [Categoria Passagem],        

           (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(B1.VR_BIL_AER),0) FROM T056TAER A1, T056BIAG B1 
            WHERE A1.CD_DOC_VIA = D.CD_DOC_VIA                                
              AND A1.DT_PRV_PGT = B1.DT_PRV_PGT
              AND A1.SQ_BIL_AER = B1.SQ_BIL_AER) AS [Valor Passagem],

           (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(R2.QT_DIA_ROT), ISNULL(case when (SELECT DATEDIFF(d,MIN(D.DT_INI_VIA) , MIN(D.DT_FIM_VIA)) FROM T056DCVI D1 WHERE D1.CD_DOC_VIA = D.CD_DOC_VIA AND D1.TP_PRS_CTA = 2) = 0 then 0 else (SELECT DATEDIFF(d,MIN(D.DT_INI_VIA) , MIN(D.DT_FIM_VIA)) FROM T056DCVI D1 WHERE D1.CD_DOC_VIA = D.CD_DOC_VIA AND D1.TP_PRS_CTA = 2) +0.5  end,0)) FROM T056RTVI R2
            WHERE R2.CD_DOC_VIA = R.CD_DOC_VIA 
              AND O.CD_ORI_CST = 1 ) AS [Número Diárias],     

           (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(O1.VR_CST_ROT),0) FROM T056CROT O1
            WHERE O1.CD_DOC_VIA = O.CD_DOC_VIA 
            AND O1.CD_ORI_CST = 1 ) AS [Valor Total Diárias],

           ((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(O1.VR_CST_ROT),0) FROM T056CROT O1
             WHERE O1.CD_DOC_VIA = O.CD_DOC_VIA )+        
           ( SELECT ISNULL(SUM(B1.VR_BIL_AER),0) FROM T056TAER A1, T056BIAG B1 
             WHERE A1.CD_DOC_VIA = D.CD_DOC_VIA                                
               AND A1.DT_PRV_PGT = B1.DT_PRV_PGT
               AND A1.SQ_BIL_AER = B1.SQ_BIL_AER)) AS [Total Viagem]

    FROM         V849EMPT E
    inner join   V849CARG C on E.CD_CG_EPG   =  C.CD_CG
    inner join   T056DCVI D on E.MT_EPG      = D.MT_EPG
    inner join   T056RTVI R on D.CD_DOC_VIA  = R.CD_DOC_VIA
    inner join   T056CROT O on R.CD_DOC_VIA  = O.CD_DOC_VIA and R.SQ_ROT_VIA = O.SQ_ROT_VIA
    inner join   T056TPVI T on D.CD_TP_VIA   = T.CD_TP_VIA
    inner join   T056TAER A on D.CD_DOC_VIA  = A.CD_DOC_VIA
    inner join   T056BIAG B on A.DT_PRV_PGT  = B.DT_PRV_PGT and A.SQ_BIL_AER = B.SQ_BIL_AER
    inner join   T056TARI I on B.CD_CIA_AER  = I.CD_CIA_AER and B.CD_TAR_AER =  I.CD_TAR_AER
    inner join   V400UNOP U1 on D.CD_ORG_DEB = U1.CD_ORG
    inner join   V400UNOP U2 on D.CD_ORG_ALC = U2.CD_ORG
    inner join   V400MUNI M1 on R.CD_CID_PTD = M1.CD_CID
    inner join   V400MUNI M2 on R.CD_CID_CGD = M2.CD_CID
    WHERE  D.DT_INI_VIA BETWEEN  '2014-05-12' and  '2015-05-20' 
      AND  D.ST_DOC_VIA = 12
      AND  O.CD_ORI_CST NOT IN (13,14)
    GROUP BY U2.NM_ORG, U1.NM_ORG, E.NM_EPG, C.NM_CG, D.CD_DOC_VIA,          
              T.NM_TP_VIA, B.DT_PRV_PGT, B.SQ_BIL_AER, O.CD_ORI_CST, 
              R.SQ_ROT_VIA, R.QT_DIA_ROT, R.CD_DOC_VIA, R.CD_CID_PTD,
              R.CD_CID_CGD, O.CD_DOC_VIA, O.SQ_ROT_VIA, B.CD_TAR_AER, 
              I.DE_TAR_AER
```

Esta aparecendo esse erro:

> Cannot specify outer join operators in a query containing joined
>   tables. View or function 'V400UNOP' contains outer join operators.

Alguém pode me ajudar.

Comment: Você pode colocar suas tabelas e a query aqui? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1):

O Erro se dá porque dentro da `V400UNOP` existe um `Outer Join` E o SQL não permite encadear o `Join` com uma `view` com `Outer Join`

O trecho é esse na claúsula `where` (script com compatibilidade SQL 2000)

```
 and n.cd_und =* cd_und_dec
```

Também recomendaria rever essa consulta, pois a mesma esta com a performance muito baixa